# Multiple JWPlayer instances on page - pause others when another plays

Tags: javascript, html, jwplayer

I have a page with several JWPlayer instances. I would like to stop, or pause the video that is playing if and when the user clicks on another one. Right now videos play at the same time and it is quite annoying.

I tried the stop and pause methods for JWPlayer but I can't get them to work.

Thank you in advance, here's my code so far (2 videos but there are several others).

```
        <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div id="video1"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                jwplayer().stop();                    
                jwplayer("video1").setup({
                    file: "video1.mp4",
                    image: "1.jpg",
                    width: "100%",
                    aspectratio: "16:9",
                    logo: { hide: true },
                    skin: "bekle"
                });
            </script>
        <p>Description</p>   
    </div>        

    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div id="video2"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                    jwplayer("video2").setup({
                    file: "video2.mp4",
                    image: "2.jpg",
                    width: "100%",
                    aspectratio: "16:9",
                    logo: { hide: true },
                    skin: "bekle"
                });                    
            </script>
        <p>Description</p>   
    </div>
```

The stop() in the first video doesn't work and actually deletes the player that doesn't load at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I iterate through all the players on the page and then make sure all are paused except for the one I want to play:

```
<script src="https://content.jwplatform.com/libraries/your_player_here.js"></script>
<div id="videoA"></div><br><br>
<div id="videoB"></div><br><br>
<div id="videoC"></div><br><br>
<div id="videoD"></div><br><br>
<script>
    jwplayer('videoA').setup({
        file: 'bunny.mp4'
    }).on('play',function(){
        pauseOthers(this.getContainer().id);    
    });

    jwplayer('videoB').setup({
        file: 'tears.mp4'
    }).on('play',function(){
        pauseOthers(this.getContainer().id);
    });

    jwplayer('videoC').setup({
        file: 'sintel.mp4'
    }).on('play',function(){
        pauseOthers(this.getContainer().id);
    });

    jwplayer('videoD').setup({
        file: 'http://content.jwplatform.com/manifests/s8BPzDe0.m3u8'
    }).on('play',function(){
        pauseOthers(this.getContainer().id);
    });

    function pauseOthers(id) {
        console.log('Playback just started for: '+id);
        var videos = document.getElementsByTagName('video');
        for (i=0;i<videos.length;i++) {
            if (id != videos[i].parentNode.parentNode.id) {
                jwplayer(videos[i].parentNode.parentNode.id).pause(true);
                console.log('Pausing: '+videos[i].parentNode.parentNode.id);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: A bit too complex for me to understand but it works, so thank you very much!